# Navbar not showing up on bootstrap

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I have seen this question asked on this site several times as it seems to be a common problem. Unfortunately none of those solutions worked for me. Below is be my code. This started after I installed Bootstrap on my Ruby on Rails app so I assume there is either a bug or I missed something.

My Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

ruby '2.5.3'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 5.2.2'
# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 3.11'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
gem 'duktape'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
# Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem 'redis', '~> 4.0'
# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'
gem 'bootstrap-sass'
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Use ActiveStorage variant
# gem 'mini_magick', '~> 4.8'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

# Reduces boot times through caching; required in config/boot.rb
gem 'bootsnap', '>= 1.1.0', require: false

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
end
group :production do
    gem 'pg'
end
group :development do
  # Access an interactive console on exception pages or by calling 'console' anywhere in the code.
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
end

group :test do
  # Adds support for Capybara system testing and selenium driver
  gem 'capybara', '>= 2.15'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
  # Easy installation and use of chromedriver to run system tests with Chrome
  gem 'chromedriver-helper'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

My application.js:

```
// This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.js, which will include all the files
// listed below.
//
// Any JavaScript/Coffee file within this directory,   lib/assets/javascripts, vendor/assets/javascripts,
// or any plugin's vendor/assets/javascripts directory can be referenced here using a relative path.
//
// It's not advisable to add code directly here, but if you do, it'll appear at the bottom of the
// compiled file. JavaScript code in this file should be added after the last require_* statement.
//
// Read Sprockets README (https://github.com/rails/sprockets#sprockets-directives) for details
// about supported directives.
//
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

My application.html.erb file which contains my Navbar:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
    <title>Website</title>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <%= csp_meta_tag %>

    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application.css" %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
  </head>





<!-- Navigation -->
<div>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-top" id="mainNav">
      <div class="container">
        <a class="navbar-brand js-scroll-trigger" href="#page-top">Alex Ross</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
          <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <div class="nav-link">
              <%= link_to 'Education/Experience', root_path(anchor: 'Education') %>
            </div>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <div class="nav-link">
              <%= link_to 'Projects', root_path(anchor: 'Projects') %>
            </div>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <div class="nav-link">
              <%= link_to 'Skills', root_path(anchor: 'Skills') %>
            </div>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <div class="nav-link">
              <%= link_to 'Certifications', root_path(anchor: 'Certifications') %>
            </div>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <div class="nav-link">
              <%= link_to 'Contact', root_path(anchor: 'Contact') %>
            </div>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </div>


    <%= yield %>
  </body>
</html>
```

My application.scss file:

```
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";
 body {
    margin: auto;
    max-width: 800px;
    padding-top: 65px;
}
a:link {

    color: white;
}
a:hover {
    color: white;
}
a:visited {
    color:white;
}

#Intro a:link { color:black; }
#Intro a:visited { color: black; }
#Intro a:hover { color: black; }
#Intro a:active { color: black; }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works now! I removed duktape from my gemfile, installed nodejs on my computer, and then rearranged application.js to look like this:

```
// This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.js, which will include all the files
// listed below.
//
// Any JavaScript/Coffee file within this directory,   lib/assets/javascripts, vendor/assets/javascripts,
// or any plugin's vendor/assets/javascripts directory can be referenced here using a relative path.
//
// It's not advisable to add code directly here, but if you do, it'll appear at the bottom of the
// compiled file. JavaScript code in this file should be added after the last require_* statement.
//
// Read Sprockets README (https://github.com/rails/sprockets#sprockets-directives) for details
// about supported directives.
//
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

Answer (score 0):

In your application.scss file:

```
@import "bootstrap";

 body {
margin: auto;
max-width: 800px;
padding-top: 65px;
 }
a:link {
color: white; 
 }
 a:hover {
color: white;
  }
a:visited {
color:white; 
  }
```

Or create new file "main.sccs":

```
 body {
margin: auto;
max-width: 800px;
padding-top: 65px;
 }
a:link {
color: white; 
 }
 a:hover {
color: white;
  }
a:visited {
color:white; 
  }
```

And  ... add import to "application.sccs" > @import "main";

Maybe error with gem.

Install gems in Gemfile:

## css

gem 'bootstrap', '~> 4.1.3'

gem 'jquery-rails'

And write in terminal "bundle i".

Comment: I tried both ways you mentioned. I now get this error:

Comment: ExecJS::ProgramError in Blogs#home 
Showing C:/Sites/Alex/website/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb where line #9 raised: 
undefined not callable